# Future not working in Slick 3.1.x

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

This function in Slick only prints "before future", it doesn't print anything within `future.map`; it seems that the future is never executed, any ideas what could be the problem?

Note: I'm running Slick standalone, not within Play

```
   def readMany = {
      val db = Database.forURL("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dddd", 
          driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", user="root", password="xxx")
      val query = TableQuery[TableDB]
      val action = query.sortBy(_.name).result
      val future = db.run(action.asTry)
      println("before future")
      future.map{ 
        case Success(s) => {
          s.map {
            row => SomeRow ( row.col1, row.col2 )
          }
          println("s:" + s)
        }
        case Failure(e) => throw new Exception ("Failure in readMany: " + e.getMessage)
        case _ => println("???")
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `case _ => println("???")` is redundant, i guess you added as debug statement. Also your `SomeRow` is never returned, your `readMany` is of type `Future[Unit]`.

Going back to your issue, if you are running that as a small code snippet, you may want to wait for your [`Future`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#blocking-outside-the-future) to complete (remember that blocking on a future in a "real-world" application is strongly discouraged):

```scala
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.Await

object Foo extends App {
  def readMany: Future[Unit] = ???
  Await.ready(readMany, 10 seconds)
}
```

> Calling Await.ready waits until the future becomes completed, but does not retrieve its result. In the same way, calling that method will not throw an exception if the future is failed.

Answer (score 1):

Your code above doesn't handle failures of the future, `future.map` only allows to handle successful results.

If there is a crash when running `db.run(action.asTry)`, the future will be failed.

To handle the failed future, you can use various methods, for example:

- `future.recover`
- `future.onFailure`
- `future.onComplete`
- ...

Comment: I appended `.recover { case e => 
          println(e)
      }` after `future.map` and still get the same result